# Sqlite update and autoincrement value

Tags: sqlite, database-schema, auto-increment

I want to update the schema of a db. I have copied the auto-generated script, but the last line after each table's script is this:

```sql
UPDATE "main"."sqlite_sequence" SET seq = 8 WHERE name = 'table';
```

The `sec` value is indeed correct for my installed DB, but it could vary on other installations. So, would it be safe to set it to 0, or should I select it from each installation's table? Or could I just skip this line and run the script without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "auto-generated" script you mean the full `.dump` of your database, then it will include the `create table` statements, and the `insert` statements, so you probably want the `update` to be executed along.

If you modify that auto-generated script, then you can obviously change the seq value as necessary.

Here is what the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) has to say:

> SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held
>   using the special SQLITE_SEQUENCE table. The SQLITE_SEQUENCE table is
>   created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that
>   contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the
>   SQLITE_SEQUENCE table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT,
>   and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will
>   likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure
>   you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

In the end, you need to make sure that the seq value matches the highest value. This demonstrates:

```
sqlite> create table foo (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, b text);
sqlite> insert into foo values (NULL, 'blabla');
sqlite> select * from foo;
1|blabla
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE foo (a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, b text);
INSERT INTO "foo" VALUES(1,'blabla');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO "sqlite_sequence" VALUES('foo',1);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I did the modifications manually in the designer and then I copied the code displayed in "SQL preview".

Comment: So, I guess if I don't modify the sql_sequence table, it should contain the correct values, that is the same as before the update, right?

Comment: Yes if you just run all the inserts for a given table, then the update to `seq` should align the sequence; OTOH there should first be an insert... do you have the insert in sqlite_sequence as well?

Comment: Yes, I have the `INSERT` query. I have done my tests, all is ok. Now, I'm going to try without the sequence update.

Comment: I added to my answer; see if it makes sense and if it is aligned with what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good solution. I think I know what to do now, thanks!